# Angular providers in module not working when imports

Tags: angular

I have a module in an angular librairie that provide an Interceptor in the forRoot method. But when i import the module in my app module the interceptor is not being use.

[the module in my librarie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtM6W.png)
[my app module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Emo.png)

Comment: What is the error you getting ??

Comment: Please put code snippet into your question. It's really difficult to help you with so little information. Check also API of your module.